# Search google for text entered in an input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to make a Google search bar for a website I am creating. I would like to search Google for the text entered in an `<input>` tag. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<script>
function googleSearch()
{
    var text=document.getElementById("search").value;
    var cleanQuery = text.replace(" ","+",text);
    var url='http://www.google.com/search?q='+cleanQuery;

    window.location.href=url;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="search" />
<button onclick="googleSearch();">Search</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty much what i wanted to do. I followed your link and ended up with this: 
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
  <input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
</form>
Which works perfectly. I just have to style it a bit.
Thanks.

Comment: After a few downvotes (probably because it wasn't specifically what you asked for, but an alternative solution), I came up with the "real" solution that you were looking for. See edited post.

Sorry for the inconvenience. :)

Comment: @Martin You are correct, and that's why I revert my DV into an UV